# Bootstrap aggregation of gradient

Tags: regression, bootstrap

I have 50 measurements repeated for each of 10 time-points, so $50\times 10$ measurements in total. So my data-set is 10 sets of 50 measurements

$$
Y_{t_i} = \{Y^{(j)}_{t_i}\,for\,j=1\dots 50\} \,for\, i=1\dots10
$$

Where $t_i$ are spaced at regular intervals. I would like to fit a simple linear model:

$$
Y_{t_i} = \alpha+t_i\times \beta + e_{t_i}
$$

The problem is that errors $e_{t_i}$ are not normally distributed and change from time-point to time-point.

Would it then be valid to randomly sample the dataset (with repetition & sampling each time-point separately). Find the OLS gradient $\beta$ for each sample, and then use order-statistics of $\beta$ to determine the confidence interval?